# How to update and add objects to a dynamically nested JSON?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a class which contains a list of its instances of the same class. This can get pretty nested and is fairly dynamic. This class has other members and therefore you can have many different cases / setups with different type of nestings.

I am trying to save it as JSON and deserialize when I need to access data.

Serializing is easy since it successfully navigates through the nesting and generates the appropriate jsons.

I am having trouble with updating. So when the session starts, I deserialize the json data that I have, I use this data when needed as a reference to load saved settings when certain elements are created.

My problem is when I want to add a new entry to the json or make updates.

To make updates, I can recursively loop through and find the item and make modifications it it but adding a new item is where I am having difficulty.

Say a few nestings down the line, I have added a new item, How can I add this to the saved JSON in the appropriate spot?

I would post my code but it spans several classes and I would need to post a lot of code.

Essentially, I have a root class and then subclasses of the same type added as children to the list and other items.

How do I determine where in the nestings the new item belongs?

I can find specific items by recursively seraching every branch for its unique ID and make edits to that item to update it but not sure how to dynamically add a new item to specific places throughout the nesting.

When first run, I just take the settings the user sets and store it as JSON.

Next time, when it is run, I deserialize the data I have and store it.

Based on what the user selects, I will load from the above step the settings for any item he selects.

If the user adds a new item, somewhere through the nestings, I need to be able to determine where, then I need to combine both the old JSON and the new JSON (ovveride old values and add new elements if any) then serialize and write to file.

I can't just serialize the new data and store it because then it would be missing the old data if it was not created in this session.

It is kind of confusing but hopefully I have been helpful enough.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand why you'd be missing old data if you deserialize the data when you begin a session. Do you have multiple simultaneous sessions running or something?

Comment: I deserialize all the data I have and store it. This is not all needed and it will only be a reference for what the user selects. The user then dynamically creates objects and this data that I deserialized is used as a reference to load the saved values from last time. On this particular session, the user will not be using all the data we have stored so not everything will be loaded into this new instance. I then serialize this new instance and if i rewrite the json with this data, it will only be the new data and the old data will be overwritten. I need to merge them.

Comment: Can you not just load everything, even if the user doesn't need it, then have the user modify that data structure, and save it out again, so that you don't have to merge when you save? You could add flags to indicate items that already existed and shouldn't be displayed in this session.

Comment: That is ideal. The code is not mine actually, I am modifying it for JSON.. It is not very well structured/designed. I oversimplified it here to help you better understand it. I would have to redesign and rework a lot to support that. As it is, this code is in a library and users use it to create instances and add stuff dynamically. This library is responsible for saving and loading saved user data whenever an instance with that name is generated. So the instance is being created no matter what (the user is creating it). This just initializes the instances to the saved values and sav

Comment: and saves the values to the files for next time that instance is created.

Comment: OK. So you you need to merge new/changed data and existing data, but you can do this with C# data-structures, before serializing to JSON?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115780/discussion-between-realist-and-blorgbeard).